# How to secure kafka connect so connection.url is not logged revealing credentials?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

The problem I am having is that credentials are being logged when running a connector, I don't want to log those.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Use this feature https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the connection.password property, the value should be masked while logging. Something like this :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
'{ 
   "name":"jdbc_source_mysql_01",
   "config":{    
      "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector"         
      "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/demo",
      "connection.user":"connect_user",
      "connection.password":"password",
      "topic.prefix":"mysql-01-",
      "mode":"bulk"
   }
}'
```

Post this the logs should look like :

```
INFO JdbcSourceTaskConfig values:
batch.max.rows = 100
connection.attempts = 3
connection.backoff.ms = 10000
connection.password = null
connection.url = jdbc:mysql://*REDACTED*
```

Comment: It's not redacted when getting the /connector/name endpoint, though

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: When you go to the REST API of the connector, passwords are still present and not redacted