# Masking in Kafka Connect logs?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to know how the secrets are being masked in Kafka. Secrets are like username, password, serviceID and apiKey and all. I don't want to log this type of information.

Comment: What you have to mask? Kafka is just a Transient Storage layer in tier web application.

Comment: @Srini Kafka is persistent and is often used as a permanent log.

Comment: @Srini Hi Srini, I have to mask user-name, password, and more secrets information while logging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure kafka connect so connection.url is not logged revealing credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961678/how-to-secure-kafka-connect-so-connection-url-is-not-logged-revealing-credential)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [apache-kafka-connect](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka-connect) you can use *secrets externalization*. This feature was implemented in [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) 2.0.0 through [KIP-297](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations).

---

*Short example:*

1. Add these properties to `connect-distributed.properties` file:

```
config.providers=file
config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider
```

2. Create a file with sensitive information (e.g. `/secrets/postgres.properties`):

   > password=strongestPasswordEver
3. Now you can use placeholders in the connector configs, e.g.:

   > "database.password": "${file:/secrets/postgres.properties:password}"

Here, the placeholder `${file:/secrets/postgres.properties:user}` says that the file config provider should be used, reading the property file `/secrets/postgres.properties` and extracting the user property from it.

---

*Great articles*:

1. [Putting Kafka Connect passwords in a separate file / externalising secrets](https://rmoff.net/2019/05/24/putting-kafka-connect-passwords-in-a-separate-file-/-externalising-secrets/)
2. [Secrets externalization with Debezium connectors](https://debezium.io/blog/2019/12/13/externalized-secrets/)

Comment: idk why but some connectors throw a login error when I use masking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what data you're logging.

Slf4j has customizable output formats. MDC context logging was recently added to the Connector loggers, but it's up to your own code logic to mask sensitive data.

Note: Kafka itself doesn't encrypt at rest either