# Masking password with a file in Kafka Connect, how to give the filepath?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to mask username and password for connector, to do that I created a file named "login" to load this information from. Read KIP [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations) and followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963295/masking-in-kafka-connect-logs) but I get ORA-01017 "Invalid username/password" error. I think there is a problem with file path, since I didn't get it exactly.

How should I give the file path, exact location as

> "/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/kafka/login"

or just the file name since it is located as the same directory as connect-distributed.properties

> "login"

> "/login"

or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should be an absolute one. For example:

```
username: ${file:/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/kafka/login:MY_ORACLE_USERNAME}
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2019/05/24/putting-kafka-connect-passwords-in-a-separate-file-/-externalising-secrets/

Comment: ok thanks, that means there is another problem with my situation.